# Problems while using Egit plugin

Tags: android

I am working on a qrcode reader app and using ZBarScanner Library. I have imported the oce and copied into workspace for eclipse. Everything works fine so far.
I am using Egit plugin to make uploading to bitbucket easier. But when I share the project in team, the project from my workspace will get copied into other folder .git and hence the referenced library loses the reference. I get errors for resources from library. I have read that its a common problem where the library we are referencing must be in the same workspace for it to work. i have tried copying the library into the .git folder but the error persists. What can I do now?

Comment: I added the worksapace as the path for committing changes and everything works!!

Comment: Please add the answer below.  That way you can select it as correct and close out your question.  Thanks.